# How to use cspack with multiple sites in one webrole?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, msbuild, azure, azure-web-roles

My csdef file is properly configured but still i cannot run cspack properly. It keeps saying that it couldn't locate the files.
When I had one site per webrole I used the parameter /role:;. With 2 sites do I need to change this?

Comment: Maybe you can share the command line you're using and the error message you're receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I was using the parameter: `/role:WebRole;MyprojectFolder`.

Now with 2 sites (2 different solutions) I'm using `/role:Webrole;FolderWithBothSites`.